# bash search for string in each line of file exclude some lines and cpy rest with same structure

Tags: bash, shell

```
i've got this file pattern 

#### data  ###
#### roles ###
11 test test22 
12 hash  hash2
13 hash3   hash77
14 hash5 ahss
14 hash5 ahss
14 hash2 adfasf
14 hash7 asfdf

#### data  ###
#### addding ###
11 test test22 
12 hash  hash2
13 hash3   hash77
14 hash5 ahss
14 hash5 ahss
14 hash2 adfasf
14 hash7 asfdf
```

I want to copy only lines start wuth 14 and exclude all other lines to output file, the output file should be same structure , like

```
#### data  ###
#### roles ###

14 hash5 ahss
14 hash5 ahss
14 hash2 adfasf
14 hash7 asfdf

#### data  ###
#### addding ###

14 hash5 ahss
14 hash5 ahss
14 hash2 adfasf
14 hash7 asfdf
```

I used grep but it wont copy the header of the file 
  #### data  ###
    #### roles ###

anytips to do it with while loop or if

Comment: You're really determined to find something that can be done with a bash loop instead of grep, aren't you?

Comment: The main tip for doing it with a `while` loop or an `if` is **don't**.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E -e '^(#|$|14 )' data.file
```

This copies lines starting with `#`, blank lines, and lines starting with `14` and a blank.

The `grep -E` is equivalent to `egrep`:

```
egrep -e '^(#|$|14 )' data.file
```

You could also do it with `sed` or `awk` (or Perl or Python), but these are more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -E`, since it allows matching alternatives:

```
grep -E '^#|^14 |^$' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash script, Save your data in data.txt and call the script

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  ret=0;
  echo $line | grep -q "^[0-9]\+\s\+[a-zA-Z0-9]\+\s\+.[a-zA-Z0-9]\+"
  ret=$?
  if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $line | grep "^14 "
  else
    echo $line;
  fi;
done < data.txt
```